# .Send is for my below vba code seems to not work

Tags: excel, vba

The below code works fine just that .Send is having issues i dont know why

```
   Sub Email_CurrentWorkBook()

Dim UserInputToEmail As String
```

'Do not forget to change the email ID before running this code

```
    Dim OlApp As Object
    Dim NewMail As Object
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim FileExt As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim FileFullPath As String
    Dim MyWb As Workbook


    Set MyWb = ThisWorkbook

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
```

TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"

```
    FileExt = "." & LCase(Right(MyWb.Name, Len(MyWb.Name) - InStrRev(MyWb.Name, ".", , 1)))
    TempFileName = MyWb.Name & "-" & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")
    FileFullPath = TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExt
    MyWb.SaveCopyAs FileFullPath
    Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set NewMail = OlApp.CreateItem(0)

    UserInputToEmail = Application.InputBox("Please enter an email address: ")

    With NewMail
        .To = UserInputToEmail
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Automated file output"
        .Body = "Hello, Please find the attached your automated script output"
        .Attachments.Add FileFullPath '
```

--- full path of the temp file where it is saved
    Dim T1 As Variant
    Dim T2 As Variant

```
    T1 = Now()
    T2 = DateAdd("s", 1, T1)

    Do Until T2 <= T1
    T1 = Now()
    Loop
    NewMail.Send
    .Send
    End With       
    On Error GoTo 0   
    Kill FileFullPath
    Set NewMail = Nothing
    Set OlApp = Nothing    
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Get rid of that `On Error Resume Next` and report back with the error that occurs when you rerun.

Comment: @BigBen Run time error 287 Application defined or object defined error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328068/runtime-error-287-sending-emails-through-outlook-using-vba-in-access might be helpful.

Comment: @BigBen the code in the link gives me an error "User Defined Type Not Defined"

Comment: @BigBen I have done the modifications as per the link you have shared but it gives error  "User Defined Type Not Defined"

Comment: Since you are working from Excel, you could try using `Application.Wait`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it doesnt seems to work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104512/how-to-send-mail-when-the-send-does-not-work